# Not able to add Index and replace header rows - Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, header

A dataframe was created by the following code:

I set a path variable

```
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

df  = []
for filename in filenames:
     df.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

frame = pd.concat(df)
```

The dataframe comes in without index(s) and I want the first row of the dataframe to be the header.

In a attempt to rename the header with the first row values, I wrote the following code and I get the following error.

```
header = frame.iloc[0]
frame2 = df[1:]
frame2.rename(columns = header)

'list' object has no attribute 'rename'
```

When I run the following, I seems to me to be a dataframe:

```
type(frame)

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

How would I go about giving the Data frame (called frame) a numbered index too.

Comment: `frame2 = df[1:]` You probably mean `frame2 = frame.iloc[1:]`.

Comment: Also this can be made much more concise: `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames])` `df.columns = df.iloc[0]` `df = df.iloc[1:].copy()`

Comment: ALollz, you're correct